# Perceptron Logical OR ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, perceptron

I found another question with almost the same title, but it was about logical AND, and I have a problem with logical OR.

This is my code:

```
from numpy import array, random, dot
from random import choice
from pylab import ylim, plot

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def step_function(x): return 0 if x < 0 else 1


training_dataset = [

    (array([0, 1, 0.2345678]), 1),

    (array([1, 0, 1]), 1),

    (array([1, 1, 0]), 0),

    (array([1, 1, 0.5]), 1),

]

weights = random.rand(3)

error = []

learning_rate = 0.00000001

n = 100

for j in range(n):
    x, expected = choice(training_dataset)
    result = dot(weights, x)
    err = expected - step_function(result)
    error.append(err)
    weights = weights + learning_rate * err * x

for i in range(100):

    result = dot(i, weights)

    print("{}: {} -> {}".format(i, result, step_function(result)))

ylim([-1,1])

plot(error)

plt.show()
```

I was trying to make a perceptron. I don't know what the problem is, but `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
happened when I changed the model evaluation loop from `for i, _ in training_dataset:` to `for i in range(100):`. I did that because it would show me the output only 4 times, and I wanted to see the program run a 100 times. Do you know why this is happening? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-loop iterated over the training_dataset, not over a range. You need to supply the dot function with a training dataset.

```
from numpy import array, random, dot
from random import choice
from pylab import ylim, plot

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def step_function(x): return 0 if x < 0 else 1


training_dataset = [

    (array([0, 1, 0.2345678]), 1),

    (array([1, 0, 1]), 1),

    (array([1, 1, 0]), 0),

    (array([1, 1, 0.5]), 1),

]

weights = random.rand(3)

error = []

learning_rate = 0.1

n = 100

for j in range(n):
    x, expected = choice(training_dataset)
    result = dot(weights, x)
    err = expected - step_function(result)
    error.append(err)
    weights = weights + learning_rate * err * x

for i in range(100):

    k = random.randint(len(training_dataset))
    
    result = dot(training_dataset[k][0], weights)

    print("{}: {} -> {}".format(i, result, step_function(result)))

ylim([-1,1])

plot(error)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! But the thing is, now it always shows an error less than 0. So when I run this, the output always becomes a "1"

Comment: Do you know of a way with which I can get rid of this problem?

Comment: It is always like this:
`0: 1.0561715964610319 -> 1
1: 0.9987895861519465 -> 1
2: 1.0561715964610319 -> 1
3: 0.9987895861519465 -> 1
4: 0.9987895861519465 -> 1
5: 1.0561715964610319 -> 1
6: 0.9987895861519465 -> 1
7: 0.15402989908124484 -> 1
8: 1.0561715964610319 -> 1
9: 1.0561715964610319 -> 1
10: 0.15402989908124484 -> 1`

Comment: Your learning rate is so small, your model isn't learning anything. Set it to something like 0.1 and you will start seeing results.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! That worked! I am quite new to AI, probably a month or so. So, I might be a bit dim-witted here. But anyway, thanks once again!